# PHP Easy mysql query if-statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, row

My Code:

```
mysql_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
mysql_select_db(SQL_DB);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".TB_PREFIX."users WHERE tribe = '2'");
if (!$result) {
die("Tribe Error");
}
```

In this code all user tribes get error. But i want only '2' tribe get error. What is wrong in this code?

Thank you.

EDIT: Please edit on my code what is wrong, please.

Comment: Don't use MySQL, use either MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements

Comment: Why? My database mysql...

Comment: @user1951205 For future users seeing your questions. If you know this, great! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @user1951205 : Mark means that you should not use mysql_* commands, but PDO or mysqli tools instead to query your mMySQL database. mysql_* commands have been deprecated for some time now.

Comment: PDO and mysqli are more modern and secure interfaces to work with MySQL. mysql_query will be deprecated in near future.

Comment: my TB_PREFIX tr and this code tr1_users. Who can edit on my code??

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the query returned an error, not if the query returned 1 (or more...) rows, which is probably what you want. A query that returns 0 rows is still a valid query.

Apart from that you should switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables.

In PDO you can probably get the number of returned rows [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php), check the manual for more details on how to rewrite your code to PDO.

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Here you can learn how to use mysqli

And the code here under, you can modefy to you own

EDIT:
this is not the right way but try this

```
mysql_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
mysql_select_db(SQL_DB);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".TB_PREFIX."users WHERE tribe = 2");
$fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if (count($fetch)<1) {
if (!$result) {
die("Tribe Error");
}
else{
var_dump($fetch);
}
```

Comment: I can't tell what i want... Sorry my bad English but i want only if user's tribe 2 get error... Not need mysqli

Comment: is your tribe column a type of int? or nvarchar?

Comment: Tribe column -> tinyint(1)

Comment: there you go your fault is probably that you compare string with int, thats imposible see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

[Mysqli on PHP official site](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Modify the code mentioned below to suit your application

```
mysql_connect(SQL_SERVER, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS);
mysql_select_db(SQL_DB);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM ".TB_PREFIX."users WHERE tribe = 2") or die(mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($fetch > 0) {
    while($dets = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        //displaying all info about current record
        var_dump($dets);
    }
}
else
    echo "No records";
```